# new_post will not create an RMarkdown post in blogdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, blogdown

I'm trying to use the hugo-future-imperfect theme but I cannot make new Rmarkdown posts using:  Addins > New Post > <>.

When I click done there is no file in the editor or in the filesystem, and the Console reports:

```
Loading required package: shiny
Warning: package ‘shiny’ was built under R version 3.3.3

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7789
Error: open : The system cannot find the file specified.
Warning: running command '"C:\Users\jrl\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" new "post/2017-06-26-test.Rmd" -k default' had status 65535
Error: open : The system cannot find the file specified.
Warning: running command '"C:\Users\jrl\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" new "post/2017-06-26-test.Rmd" -k default' had status 65535
The system cannot find the path specified.
Warning: running command 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c "C:\Users\jrl\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" new "post/2017-06-26-test.Rmd" -k default' had status 1
Warning: Error in shell: '"C:\Users\jrl\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" new "post/2017-06-26-test.Rmd" -k default' execution failed with error code 1
Stack trace (innermost first):
    82: shell
    81: shell2
    80: system2
    79: hugo_cmd
    78: new_content
    77: blogdown::new_post
    76: observeEventHandler
    12: shiny::runApp
    11: shiny::runGadget
    10: eval
     9: eval
     8: eval
     7: eval
     6: eval.parent
     5: local
     4: eval
     3: eval
     2: sys.source
     1: blogdown:::new_post_addin
```

---

The steps I used to build the site were:

blogdown::new_site(theme = 'jpescador/hugo-future-imperfect')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a bug that has been fixed in Hugo 0.24.1 the other day. Please restart your R session, try to reinstall **blogdown**, and update Hugo:

```
devtools::install_github('rstudio/blogdown')
blogdown::update_hugo()
```

Comment: Thanks.  That took care of it.  It's all working now.

Comment: Glad to know that! Thanks for the confirmation!